# For loop with Javascript to get values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have this variable named: var **quantity**.

This variable changes continuously. For example: *quantity = 1, quantity = 26...*

On the other hand I have an array of elements with prices according to the quantity of the product: var quantity_prices.

```
var quantity_prices = [
    {
        "quantity": 1,
        "price_pvp": 7.96
    }, {
        "quantity": 5,
        "price_pvp": 7.96
    }, {
        "quantity": 15,
        "price_pvp": 6.97
    }, {
        "quantity": 25,
        "price_pvp": 5.97
    }
];
```

I want to make that if quantity is between quantities 1 and 5, 6 and 14, 15 and 24, the product has the right price.
Example:
if the quantity is 16, the price I want to take is: 5,95€.

I've thought about using a for loop but I don't know how to continue to make this work what I want to do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.quantity_prices.length; i++) { // if quantity is between 1 and 5
    new_price = this.quantity_prices[i].price_pvp;
    // elseif quantity is between 6 and 14
    new_price = this.quantity_prices[i].price_pvp;
    // elseif quantity is between 15 and 24
    new_price = this.quantity_prices[i].price_pvp;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Loop through the array until you find an item where the `quantity` of the element is greater than the actual quantity. The element before that is the one with the price.

Comment: In your code replace the comments with ```if (quantity < top price)``` then use the price of that group. Do this in your if..then... else structure. It should work

Comment: ***Example: if the quantity is 16, the price I want to take is: 5,95*** - based on what?

Comment: Do you want discount levels (15-16-17-18-...-24 would all cost 6.97, although the example says something else), interpolate between "disount control points" (15 cost 6.97, 16 cost a bit less, 17 a bit even less, arriving to 5.97 at 25), or calculate price for an amount using the available quantities (16=15+1, so 15*6.97+7.96=112.51, or 7.03 per piece)? All of them are possible, and the example does not exactly help to decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var quantity_prices = [
    {
    "quantity": 1,
    "price_pvp": 7.96,
    },
    {
    "quantity": 5,
    "price_pvp": 7.96,
    },
    {
    "quantity": 15,
    "price_pvp": 6.97,
    },
    {
    "quantity": 25,
    "price_pvp": 5.97,
    }
    ];

for(let i=0;i<quantity_prices.length;i++){
    if(quantity_prices[i].quantity>0 && quantity_prices[i].quantity<5 )
      {
          //whatever the required output you want.
        quantity_prices[i].new_price=quantity_prices[i].price_pvp;

      }if(quantity_prices[i].quantity>6 && quantity_prices[i].quantity<14){

     }
     if(quantity_prices[i].quantity>15 && quantity_prices[i].quantity<24){

     }
}
console.log(quantity_prices)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group according to your req as per below code and then print the price.

```js
var quantity_prices = [{
    "quantity": 1,
    "price_pvp": 7.96,
  },
  {
    "quantity": 5,
    "price_pvp": 7.96,
  },
  {
    "quantity": 15,
    "price_pvp": 6.97,
  },
  {
    "quantity": 25,
    "price_pvp": 5.97,
  }
];

var group1_5 = quantity_prices.filter(q => q.quantity >= 1 && q.quantity <= 5);
console.log(group1_5);

//print your price
if (group1_5.length > 0) {
  console.log(group1_5[0].price_pvp)
}

var group6_16 = quantity_prices.filter(q => q.quantity >= 6 && q.quantity <= 14);
console.log(group6_16);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the right quantity, then return the price for this amount.

I'm assuming that if the quantity is not found directly we'll return the next entry in the quantity / price table.

```js
const quantity_prices = [ { "quantity": 1, "price_pvp": 7.96, }, { "quantity": 5, "price_pvp": 7.96, }, { "quantity": 15, "price_pvp": 6.97, }, { "quantity": 25, "price_pvp": 5.97, } ];

function getPrice(quantity, priceLookup) {
    let entry = priceLookup.find((e,index) => e.quantity >= quantity || index === priceLookup.length-1);
    return entry.price_pvp;
}

console.log("Price table:");
const quantities = [1,4,5,10,15,16,25,26,30];
for(let quantity of quantities ) {
    console.log(`Price (${quantity }): €${getPrice(quantity, quantity_prices)}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try it with this:

```
                 function check(){
                   this.quantity_prices.find(({price}) => {
                      if(price_pvp > 1 && price_pvp < 5){
                         // do something
                      }
                      if(price_pvp > 6 && price_pvp < 14){
                         // do something
                      }
                      if(price_pvp > 15 && price_pvp < 24){
                         // do something
                      }
                   }
                 }
```